# Is there any way to switch Platinum and Gold in the world?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, when you create a world, there are only certain materials that generate in that world, specifically ores. Platinum and gold are examples. Can you change the ore a world generates?

Answer (score 8):

You can not change the ore a world is set to generate, however, I have come up with two solutions that do me quite well.

#### Using the Extractinator: Farming Silt and Slush

With an [Extractinator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Extractinator), you can convert Silt and Slush into any number of useful materials. While completely random, you will commonly receive coins, jewels and ore. Before creating my off-world mines, this was a stable source for silver, gold and platinum. I also found it to be the quickest way to earn gold. I understand I got very lucky in finding one so early in the game, with ice chests having only a 5% chance to contain one, however until you're as lucky, just **make sure you're putting all that silt and slush away, and don't destroy it.**

#### Generate Mining Worlds

Once I pulled my character up a bit to take on the underworld, I got myself kitted out with [Mining Gear](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mining_armor). The helmet, alone, gives you a free light source. With the other two pieces, you gain a 30% increase to mining speed.

I then generated a new world, and proceeded to turn it into an "off-world mine". Dig tunnels through the world, until you find the materials you are after. Dig out a bit, to reach lower levels that contain higher-value ores, and dig out tunnels in a checkered pattern - it just makes it easier to navigate back to the farthest reaches. If you take a spare bed with you, you often find the odd underground house you can use to set up a safe re-spawn.

Off-world mines are still limited to the ore they generate; however, they can also be a very good source of silt and slush, to which I direct you back to heading one.

Comment: Note since 1.3 extractinators are much easier to find, as it may appear in fishing crates or found already placed in underground desert cabins.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a checkered pattern, are you referring to branch mining?

Comment: The question isn't "How do I obtain x ore?"... So to be completely honest, nothing but the first half line of your answer is really relevant :\

Comment: Another option is to fish for crates-- Crates have an equal chance to get gold and platinum ores and bars.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No

The world will be generated with only one of these ores (chosen at random) and once generated, you cannot change the world other than through standard gameplay.

Without using a world editor, a world cannot contain natural ores of a type it didn't generate with. Though people could still bring ore mined from another world in and place it.

If you specifically want a world with one type rather than the other, your best option is simply to generate a few worlds and wait until you get one with the ores you want.